# How to dynamically change orientation within DataTable's pdfHtml5 button?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, datatables, orientation, pdfmake

I have been trying to change the orientation of the output in DataTables dynamically depending on how many columns are visible.

I am setting a global variable, dynOrient, that I calculate as the user shows/hides columns. I then have tried setting it in the button options:

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        footer: true,
        text: 'Download PDF',
        orientation: dynOrient,    //HERE
        customize: function(doc) {
        ...
        }
    }
]
```

This seems to keep whatever dynOrient was when the button was created, without changing it from landscape to portrait later as dynOrient changes.

I have also tried putting it in the customize function:

```
doc.content[1].pageOrientation = dynOrient;
```

This didn't do anything, just kept the default portrait no matter what dynOrient is.

How can I dynamically change the orientation of the pdfHtml5 output in DataTables?

Answer (score 1):

change pdf orientation in the customize section

```
extend: 'pdfHtml5',    
customize: function (doc) {
   doc.pageOrientation=yourOrientation;
}
```

Note : yourOrientation is your orientation parameter or a function that return 'landscape' or 'portrait'

the customize section is always called when export to pdf

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured out *a* solution (I don't know if it's the proper solution though).

I put the information for the button into a global variable, and every time a column get's shown or hidden, I re-calculate the orientation, set the orientation manually in the button information, and remove/recreate the button.

```
var buttonInfo = {
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    footer: true,
    text: 'Download PDF',
    orientation: dynOrient,
    customize: function(doc) {
    ...
    }
};

//some code...

$("input[name='showhideswitches']").click(function() {
    var col = $(this).data('col');
    myTable.column(col).visible($(this).prop("checked"));
    dynOrient = getOrientation();
    buttonInfo.orientation = dynOrient; //Manually overriding orientation
    myTable.button('0').remove();
    myTable.button().add(0, buttonInfo); //Re-create
}
```

Maybe someone can offer a better solution, but until then I'm going to keep this in since it works for now.